# Is there a way to fetch cache keys by a pattern or a cache tag

Tags: caching, 9

I was trying to find if there is a way to fetch or count Drupal cache keys that match a pattern. I couldn't find a function in the CacheBackendInterface that does this.

The context is that I was trying to see if there is some way to show statistics around the different types of cache keys being used.

Comment: Because the cache is supposed to be a keystore, where you can only fetch items by their exact key (meaning it can be implemented using a wide range of different technologies), wildcard queries are not supported. Also cache entries are not guaranteed to be persistent, so stats may mislead. DB cache can be queried as you suggest, other cache mechanisms not necessarily. You'll have to write your own interface to whichever you are using.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @AlfredArmstrong